# Firebase reading data two times from firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to read the data from a Firebase Firestore collection called 'posts'. Its having few documents in it. When I am using the following code to read data, I am able to read it but two times:

- code in posts.jsx file:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import '../index.css';
import '../../node_modules/antd/dist/antd.min.css';
import PostSnippet from './PostSnippet';
import _ from 'lodash';
import { PageHeader } from "antd";
import { db } from '../firebase.js';
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";


function Posts(props) {

  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const postRef = collection(db, 'posts');
      const postSnap = await getDocs(postRef);
      postSnap.forEach(doc => {
        let data = doc.data()
        let { id } = doc

        let payload = {
          id,
          ...data,
        }
        setPosts((posts) => [...posts, payload])
      })
    }

    fetchData()
      .catch(console.error);

  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="posts_container">
      <div className="page_header_container">
        <PageHeader
          style={{
            border: '5px solid rgb(235, 237, 240)',
            fontSize: '25px',
            margin: '40px',
          }}
          title="Post"
        />
      </div>

      <div className="articles_container">
        {
          _.map(posts, (article, idx) => {
            return (
              <PostSnippet
                key={idx}
                id={article.id}
                title={article.title}
                content={article.content.substring(0, 300)} />
            )
          })
        }

      </div>
    </div>
  )
}


export default Posts;
```

- Code in PostSnippet.jsx file which is used to give the view to individual cards:

```
import React from "react";
import { Card } from "antd";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const PostSnippet = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="post_snippet_container" style={{ margin: "40px" }}>
        <Card
          type="inner"
          title={props.title}
          extra={
            <Link to={`/post/${props.id}`}>
              Refer the Article
            </Link>}
        >
          <p className="article_content">
            {
              props.content.split('\n').map((paragraph, idx) => {
                return <p key={idx}>{paragraph}</p>
              })
            }
          </p>
        </Card>
      </div>
    </>

  )
}


export default PostSnippet;
```

- Actual data in Firestore:
  [image]
- Retried data from the firestore:
  [image]

Comment: Are you by chance using React 18 and [strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state)? If so, that is expected. In development builds, strict mode intentionally simulates unmounting and remounting your components to help you catch errors from failing to clean up when unmounting. Since the component effectively mounts twice, the effect runs twice.

Comment: @NicholasTower, yes I am using react 18.2.0 and strict mode with React. Is there a way to fix it in react 18 only while using the strict mode ?

Comment: Is it causing you a problem? The extra mount will not happen in a production build. It doesn't look to me like anything needs fixing.

Comment: Yes, its reading the data from the Firestore and displaying it two times as I am reading all the documents from the collection directly.

Comment: Are you saying that the UI shows a list which is twice as long as expected, because the items are duplicated? Or are you saying the network traffic and cpu usage is higher than you would like because of the double fetch, but everything looks good on the screen?

Comment: Yes, its showing the list two times. I have added some pictures showing the firestore and retried console out put for your reference.

Comment: Most likely the problem is where you're setting state, so we'll need to see that to tell you how to fix it. It may also help for us to see where you map the items into JSX elements.

Comment: @NicholasTower, I have added both the posts jsx and individual post snip jsx file for your reference. Let me know your findings if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setPosts((posts) => [...posts, payload])
```

You only ever add to the array, so when data is fetched for the second time, you grow your array to twice the size. Instead, replace the array with the new data. That way the second fetch will overwrite the first:

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  const postRef = collection(db, 'posts');
  const postSnap = await getDocs(postRef);
  const newPosts = postSnap.docs.map(doc => {
    return {
      id: doc.id,
      ...doc.data(),
    }
  });
  setPosts(newPosts);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nicholas for the answer. It worked perfectly :)